# Special Characters PHPmail

Tags: php, character

First of all please apologize my English.

I'm having a problem with PHPmail, I'm using PHPmailer to send mails, using file_get_contents( file dir ) to send an html email..

but when I recieve the email, special characters are showing as: Â Ã³l and etc.

The email template I'm using is in this URL: http://zicher.mx/procesos/content/c_acc/index.html and showing all as expected, because of course I have this meta tag in my template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Have any idea of why this is happening?, its like Gmai is ignoring the UTF-8 cofification.

Comment: Are you declaring the MIME part as UTF8? Is the file actually encoded as UTF8?

Comment: Sorry but don't know what is that

Comment: its like declaring UTF-8 in mail headers?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just googled MIME and solved with this: $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

Comment: @SLaks Please submit your comment as an answer so that Guillermo Esquivel has an answer to award the green tick to.  Otherwise this question will never appear resolved and will appear permanently abandoned.

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivel  If SLaks doesn't submit an answer in the next couple of days, feel free to submit a thoughtful/informative answer yourself and mark it as accepted.  (But first, do the honorable thing and allow time for SLaks to supply his answer and receive the rep points for his advice to you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<meta>` tag is equivalent to HTTP headers; it has no effect in emails.

You need to set the `Content-Type` of your HTML MIME part to indicate UTF 8 encoding.